# Woocommerce - некорректное отображение товаров в ряд в магазине

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте! 
  Помогите пожалуйста разобраться! Некорректно отображается каталог товаров в woocommerce. Стоит "Visual Composer". У него в настройках все верно, стоит сетка, отображение 6 в ряд, а отображется только 3 товара, на половину страницы, хотя там больше нет никаких блоков. 
  Тема Nilsen. В чем может быть проблема и где что в коде поменять? Фото прилагаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы не плохо код/разметку (если он конечно Ваш:)) увидеть, а то по фото гадать сложно. Посмотрите на `margin`'ы в первую очередь...

Answer (score 1):

Так потому, что у Вас WooCommerce выводит 3 товара в ряд.

Если Вы хотите 6 товаров в ряд, то надо добавить следующий код в `functions.php`:

```
// Установить число товаров в ряд в 6
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 6; // 6 товаров в ряд
    }
}
```

Comment: На главной отображение 6 в ряд должно быть, в магазине 4 в ряд, отображается ровно половина. По вашему сделала, стало в магазине отображаться не два товара до половины, а 3, но все равно до середины листа. Может все дело style.css? Не знаю куда его тут прикрепить.

Comment: А вот это, что на картинке, Вы как выводите? Шорткодом на главной?

Comment: В "Visual Composer" блок "Show the Prodacts". В настройках "Grid" , выводить 6 в ряд, выводит только 3 до половины. Вот ссылка на магазин http://caucasus-blade.com/ в главном меню SHOP в настройках должно выводиться 4 в ряд, а выводиться тоже до половины 2. Буду очень рада если сможете помочь в чем дело!)

Comment: вот что я вижу на сайте: http://take.ms/8vU9N      - 6 в ряд в чем проблема?

Comment: Все получилось! на другом форуме подсказали, что надо поменять в woocommerce файле style.css 324 строку.
ul.products li.product.first{clear: both;}
Убрать clear: both, посмотреть результат.